# Oracle Form Compilation

Tags: oracle

I have a WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger to validate the data. If failed it should prompt error message to inform the users this input data is probably invalid. 

I compile the form without any changes, nothing happen. But after I modified the PL/SQL (in fact I just added one new blank line), seems like the WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM gets compiled.

Do you have any idea how could this happen? My assumption is when I modify something on the WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM even I just adding a space, Oracle Forms Builder will consider this component as modified and will put this component into a list to be compiled. 

Please correct me if I am wrong. 

Thanks. 

Jonas

Comment: Makes sense, yes.  What is the problem here though?

Comment: I am working with a form to create order. Logically one Customer PO Number should only exists in one organization. Therefore, if user entered a duplicate PO Number, we should prompt message to user. This checking is gone after we complete an server upgrade. But in fact, the code is exactly the same as the previous version. But after I modified the **fmb** file (added one new blank line) and compile the form again, it's working now but I have no idea why.